# Get Laravel 5 controller name in view

Tags: laravel-5

Our old website CSS was set up so that the `body` tag had an id of the controller name and a class of the action name, using Zend Framework 1.  Now we're switching to Laravel 5.  I found a way to get the action name through the `Route` class, but can't find a method for the controller name.  I don't see anything in the Laravel docs like this.  Any ideas?

This is how you do with action.  You inject the Route class, and then call:

`$route->getActionName()`.

I'm looking for something similar for controllers.  I've checked the entire route class and found nothing.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If your layout is a Blade template, you could create a view composer that injects those variables into your layout. In **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php** add something like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    app('view')->composer('layouts.master', function ($view) {
        $action = app('request')->route()->getAction();

        $controller = class_basename($action['controller']);

        list($controller, $action) = explode('@', $controller);

        $view->with(compact('controller', 'action'));
    });
}
```

You will then have two variables available in your layout template: `$controller` and `$action`.

Comment: I like that.  It's not quite what I need, but I see what you're doing and I can adapt it. Thanks!

Comment: @sehummel Awesome! Glad I was able to steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @MartinBean I was searching this output, for automating the Entrust roles and permission. When I used 
`code` app('request')->route()->getAction(); `code`
 in middleware, I got FatalErrorException  as call a member function getAction() on a non-object
But, when I wrote this code into Service provider it worked?
Can you help me,how to get it working in middleware!?

Comment: @MartinBean : this is the question (task) I am expecting
[answer to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235639/automate-entrust-permission-with-accessing-the-route-name-parameters-and-check-f)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is not working in my scenario. I am using laravel `5.1`

Answer (score 16):

I use a simple solution. You can test and use it in everywhere, also in your views:

```
{{ dd(request()->route()->getAction()) }}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!!

Comment: But, this is giving a long string `"App\Http\Controllers\LocalLeadsSearch@index"` and I only want `LocalLeadsSearch`

Comment: @AnujTBE TBE You can easily separate string wit explode() PHP method ; )

Comment: @AnujTBE you could define your controller name in route. e.g.,
Route::get('/getProducts','searchAmazon@index')->name("searchAmazon.index");
Then you could get it from {{ dd(request()->route()->getAction()['as']) }}

Answer (score 4):

I will simply use as bellow

```php
$request->route()->getActionMethod()
```

Answer (score 2):

To get something like PostController try following ...

```
preg_match('/([a-z]*)@/i', $request->route()->getActionName(), $matches);
$controllerName = $matches[1];
```

$matches[1] includes the first group while $matches[0] includes everything matched. So also the @ which isn't desired.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
strtok(substr(strrchr($request->route()->getActionName(), '\\'), 1), '@')
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Martin Bean answer, using Route::view in your routes will cause the list function to throw an **Undefined offset error** when this code runs;

`list($controller, $action) = explode('@', $controller);`

Instead use this, which assigns null to $action if not present

`list($controller, $action) = array_pad(explode('@', $controller), 2, null);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to just simply display in the title like "Customer - My Site" (laravel 9)

```
{{ str_replace('Controller', '', strtok(substr(strrchr(request()->route()->getActionName(), '\\'), 1), '@'))}} - {{ config('app.name') }}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add this (**tested with Laravel v7+**)

```
<?php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

    echo Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionMethod();
?>
```

or

You can use helper function

```
<?php echo request()->route()->getActionMethod(); ?>
```

for example :-

> Route::get('test', [\App\Http\Controllers\ExampleController::class, 'exampleTest'])->name('testExample');

Now If I request `{app_url}/test` then it will return `exampleTest`