# Best practice for creating administrator area interface in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, admin

I have recently started learning Laravel 5 and i need to create a seperate administrator area within the site.

I have tried a lot to get the file directory structure but most of them i got are for Laravel 4 and not for the Laravel 5.

As Laravel 5 differs in the structure from Laravel 4.

Can anyone please help me how to setup the the directory structure for the administrator area and the routings.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about doing it the simple way. You can create resources/views/admin for all your admin views then app\admin for all admin models , controllers and other admin stuffs

Comment: Have you seen this package? Is for laravel 5 : https://github.com/serverfireteam/panel

Comment: @Digitlimit Thanks for the reply. I ll give a try tonight following your first comment.

For the second comment: Its good but have some issues in the backend and is not bugfree, do you have more examples like this?

Comment: You can study the package and pickup some ideas

Comment: Are you going to have a separate admins table from default users table?

Comment: @pinkalvansia Nope It will be in the same table with different type and access level

Comment: @Digitlimit I tried following the steps for installation but ended with error.
Can you please suggest where to place the panel folder before updating composer

Comment: I have not really used that package in my project. :)

Comment: There have been two packages I have used for creating admin areas, frozennode/administrator, is great for easy config, but if you want more control and a more elegant interface, take a look at acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel. Of course adminlte required you to write you own views whereas frozennode does all of that for you.

Comment: @Azeame frozennode works till Laravel 4

Comment: @Azeame Can you please guide me where to place the adminlte-laravel-master folder in the laravel 5 before following installation instruction

Comment: @Veerenda you are right frozennode will only work until Laravel 4 by default but I have found that changing the name of one method call in one of the files makes it compatible with Laravel 5, but I can't remember how I make it work because it's been a long time since I last used it.

Comment: @Vereenda I followed the following guide to get adminlte working in a project https://almsaeedstudio.com/blog/integrate-adminlte-with-laravel

Comment: @Azeame Where to place the adminlite folder after downloading it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had recently create a project in Laravel 5 with Admin area. I had used advanced ACL (Access Control Layer)  to give role wise admin permissions. For this I had used [Entrust Package](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust). Then I used the basic auth of Laravel 5 and had implement Entrust.

I had easily created the admin area with all the permissions. I have also tried to set automatic permissions within `Authenticate.php` middleware

You can reference this [Entrust Automate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235639/automate-entrust-permission-with-accessing-the-route-name-parameters-and-check-f) stack question, I had asked. But later I found the solution. 
I would suggest you to follow URL based architecture then the old way of folder structure to manage the Admin. Laravel 5 is best for URL based which will also help you to create any API's if you need in future for mobile apps.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I usually make my own back-end, with packages like [entrust](https://github.com/zizaco/entrust) and a random bootstrap template that fits my needs.
Then I just put my views in views/admin and my controllers in Controller/admin and put all admin routes in a group with a middleware attached to it

```
    Route::group(['namespace'=>'Admin','prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>'role','role'=>'admin'],function(){
        Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
}
```

and then in the middleware (this is using [entrust](https://github.com/zizaco/entrust)).

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = $this->auth->user();
        $route = $request->route();
        if($user && $route)
        {
            $actions = $route->getAction();
            if(array_key_exists('role',$actions)) {
                $role=$actions['role'];
                if(!$user->hasRole($role)) {
                    Flash::error('Unauthorized Access');

                    abort(401);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Flash::error('Unauthorized Access');
                abort(401);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Flash::error('Unauthorized Access');
            abort(401);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Don't forget to register the middleware in the kernel.php next to the routes file.

The middleware might look complicated but is simply checks if you have put a role in your group en then if the currently logged in user belongs to that group.

Also remember that when you route using `action()`, you need to put the admin namespace before the controller name like `action('Admin\HomeController@index')`