# How to know the controller and method name inside blade file in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I am new to Laravel. I was practicing setting up a blog in **Laravel 6**. I have a `layout.blade.php` file where all the basic HTML is written. In the content section of the `layout.blade file`, I want to `@include` other blade file depending on the controller and method name.

I have 2 controllers, `HomeController` and `ArticleController`. In `HomeController` file, there is a method `index()` which returns the view `home.blade.php`. Again, `home.blade.php` `@extends` `layout.blade.php`. Now I want to know which controller and method called the view file inside from `layout.blade.php` file.

I want something like this-

```
<!-- This is layout.blade.php file -->
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  @if (Controller == HomeController AND Method == index)
    @include('home')
  @endif

  @if (Controller == ArticleController AND Method == index)
    @include('articles')
  @endif
</body>
</html>
```

I didn't find any answer on Google. I got some questions in StackOverflow, but they have very confusing answers and those versions are older also.

Thank you.

EDIT 1:

1. Due to the low reputation score, I cannot reply in comments. As I am
   new, I know some basic tags of blade, so if there is any other
   solution to achieve this, please share it with me.
2. I found
   [Get Laravel 5 controller name in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549660/get-laravel-5-controller-name-in-view)
   before making this question. But I don't think it answers my
   question.
3. I know `Controller == HomeController AND Method == index` is crazy.
   I just illustrated what I need. I know basic `@yield` and `@section`
   tags, but I don't want to use this in my case. Because, if I make a
   card/home section entirely in a different file, I can call it in
   other files later. If I use `@yield`, I will have to use `@section` in
   different files also, which I don't want to do.

Comment: I think `Route::currentRouteAction()` should do the trick but your approach seems weird to me. Maybe a blade `@stack` could suit your needs better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Laravel 5 controller name in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549660/get-laravel-5-controller-name-in-view)

Comment: @IGP, please share it as an answer. This is what I wanted.

Comment: @YasinPate, I found the question before making this question, but sadly it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @S.M.Khalilullah, instead of checking controller and action, directly check with route url by : if(Request::url() === 'your url here')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Route::currentRouteAction()` method seems to be what you want. It's in the api documentation.

> `string|null` `currentRouteAction()`
>
> Get the current route action.
>
> Return Value
>   `string|null`

https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_currentRouteAction

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, you do not need to do this crazy thing like this

```php
Controller == HomeController AND Method == index
```

If all you want is to setup a master page. Laravel makes it really easy.

This is the master page.

```html
<!-- Stored in resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For other pages

```html
<!-- Stored in resources/views/index.blade.php -->

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content. From index page.</p>
@endsection
```

And for the controller, you just return the blade.php view file name.

```php
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to use yield-section. Rather, I want to use something like include because if I make a file for a specific section, I can include it anywhere without defining the section.

Answer (score -1):

I run this one to know the controller. You can try it.

```
{{ dd(request()->route()->getAction()) }}
```