# Livewire error Undefined offset: 1 AppServiceProvider.php:222. Livewire click and changing value in the text area giving error this error

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Can anyone say why this is happening?

Just a simple count component.
Even the data binding also throws the same error when changing the value in the text box.
Any help would be appreciated.
I have used a simple counter component. By clicking on the button it is giving this error.
Also when I am using the data binding mechanism this same error is happening.
I am very new in laravel-livewire.
[Undefined offset: 1 AppServiceProvider.php:222](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOmDk.gif)

Stak Trace

```
  ErrorException:
  Undefined offset: 1
  
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:222
    at Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined offset: 1', '/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php', 222, array('view' => object(View), 'route' => object(Route), 'action' => array('uses' => 'Livewire\\Controllers\\HttpConnectionHandler@__invoke', 'controller' => 'Livewire\\Controllers\\HttpConnectionHandler', 'as' => 'livewire.message', 'middleware' => array('web')), 'controller' => 'HttpConnectionHandler'))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:222)
    at Acelle\Providers\AppServiceProvider->Acelle\Providers\{closure}(object(View))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Concerns/ManagesEvents.php:162)
    at Illuminate\View\Factory->Illuminate\View\Concerns\{closure}('composing: counter', array(object(View)))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:401)
    at Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure}('composing: counter', array(object(View)))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:249)
    at Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->dispatch('composing: counter', array(object(View)))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Concerns/ManagesEvents.php:177)
    at Illuminate\View\Factory->callComposer(object(View))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php:120)
    at Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php:91)
    at Illuminate\View\View->render()
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Component.php:233)
    at Livewire\Component->output()
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/HydrationMiddleware/RenderView.php:14)
    at Livewire\HydrationMiddleware\RenderView::dehydrate(object(Counter), object(Response))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/LifecycleManager.php:154)
    at Livewire\LifecycleManager->dehydrate()
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Connection/ConnectionHandler.php:15)
    at Livewire\Connection\ConnectionHandler->handle(array('fingerprint' => array('id' => 'ngiHyKZX088zJGRx1sYl', 'name' => 'counter', 'locale' => 'en', 'path' => 'inbox', 'method' => 'GET'), 'serverMemo' => array('children' => array(), 'errors' => array(), 'htmlHash' => '6a2610a1', 'data' => array('steps' => 0), 'dataMeta' => array(), 'checksum' => '8e1ff8cf773a9a2ba8d81712fcabf60c2e99b9952544ea9bffa4594840def420'), 'updates' => array(array('type' => 'callMethod', 'payload' => array('id' => '1a8g', 'method' => 'increment', 'params' => array())))))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Controllers/HttpConnectionHandler.php:20)
    at Livewire\Controllers\HttpConnectionHandler->__invoke('counter')
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:48)
    at Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(HttpConnectionHandler), '__invoke')
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:262)
    at Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:205)
    at Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:695)
    at Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:128)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:50)
    at Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:78)
    at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php:49)
    at Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:121)
    at Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(object(Request), object(Store), object(Closure))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:64)
    at Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php:37)
    at Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:67)
    at Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:103)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:697)
    at Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:672)
    at Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(object(Request), object(Route))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:636)
    at Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:625)
    at Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:167)
    at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:128)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/DisableBrowserCache.php:19)
    at Livewire\DisableBrowserCache->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php:27)
    at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php:36)
    at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php:27)
    at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php:86)
    at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:103)
    at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:142)
    at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:111)
    at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/public/main.php:52)
    at require('/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/public/main.php')
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/public/index.php:60)
    at require_once('/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/public/index.php')
      (/opt/lampp/htdocs/cowe-new/server.php:21)
```

AppServiceProvider.php

```
        <?php
        
        namespace Acelle\Providers;
        
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
        use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
        use URL;
        use Acelle\Model\Setting;
        use Acelle\Library\HookManager;
        use Acelle\Model\Plugin;
        use Acelle\Model\Notification;
        use Acelle\Library\BillingManager;
        use Acelle\Library\Facades\Hook;
        
        class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
        {
            /**
            * Bootstrap any application services.
            */
            public function boot()
            {
                // Teak default settings (PHP, Laravel, etc.)
                $this->changeDefaultSettings();
        
                // Add custom validation rules
                // @deprecated
                $this->addCustomValidationRules();
        
                // Just finish if the application is not set up
                if (!isInitiated()) {
                    return;
                }
        
                // Load application's plugins
                // Disabled plugin may also register hooks
                $this->loadPlugins();
            }
        
            /**
            * Register any application services.
            *
            * @return void
            */
            public function register()
            {
                $this->app->singleton(HookManager::class, function ($app) {
                    return new HookManager();
                });
        
                $this->app->singleton(BillingManager::class, function ($app) {
                    return new BillingManager();
                });
        
                Hook::register('add_translation_file', function () {
                    return [
                        "id" => "Acelle_messages",
                        "plugin_name" => "Acelle/Core",
                        "file_title" => "Messages",
                        "translation_folder" => base_path('resources/lang'),
                        "file_name" => "messages.php",
                        "default" => "default",
                        "type" => 'default',
                    ];
                });
        
                Hook::register('add_translation_file', function () {
                    return [
                        "id" => "Acelle_auth",
                        "plugin_name" => "Acelle/Core",
                        "file_title" => "Auth",
                        "translation_folder" => base_path('resources/lang'),
                        "file_name" => "auth.php",
                        "default" => "default",
                        "type" => 'default',
                    ];
                });
        
                Hook::register('add_translation_file', function () {
                    return [
                        "id" => "Acelle_pagination",
                        "plugin_name" => "Acelle/Core",
                        "file_title" => "Pagination",
                        "translation_folder" => base_path('resources/lang'),
                        "file_name" => "pagination.php",
                        "default" => "default",
                        "type" => 'default',
                    ];
                });
        
                Hook::register('add_translation_file', function () {
                    return [
                        "id" => "Acelle_passwords",
                        "plugin_name" => "Acelle/Core",
                        "file_title" => "Passwords",
                        "translation_folder" => base_path('resources/lang'),
                        "file_name" => "passwords.php",
                        "default" => "default",
                        "type" => 'default',
                    ];
                });
        
                Hook::register('add_translation_file', function () {
                    return [
                        "id" => "Acelle_builder",
                        "plugin_name" => "Acelle/Core",
                        "file_title" => "Builder",
                        "translation_folder" => base_path('resources/lang'),
                        "file_name" => "builder.php",
                        "default" => "default",
                        "type" => 'default',
                    ];
                });
        
                Hook::register('add_translation_file', function () {
                    return [
                        "id" => "Acelle_validation",
                        "plugin_name" => "Acelle/Core",
                        "file_title" => "Validation",
                        "translation_folder" => base_path('resources/lang'),
                        "file_name" => "validation.php",
                        "default" => "default",
                        "type" => 'default',
                    ];
                });
            }
        
            private function loadPlugins()
            {
                try {
                    Plugin::autoload();
                    Notification::cleanupDuplicateNotifications('Plugin Error');
                } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                    // Just in case
                    Notification::warning([
                        'message' => 'Cannot load Acelle plugins. Error: '.htmlspecialchars($ex->getMessage()),
                        'title' => 'Plugin Error',
                    ]);
                }
            }
        
            // @deprecated
            private function addCustomValidationRules()
            {
                // extend substring validator
                Validator::extend('substring', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
                    $tag = $parameters[0];
                    if (strpos($value, $tag) === false) {
                        return false;
                    }
        
                    return true;
                });
                Validator::replacer('substring', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
                    return str_replace(':tag', $parameters[0], $message);
                });
        
                // License validator
                Validator::extend('license', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
                    return $value == '' || true;
                });
        
                // License error validator
                Validator::extend('license_error', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
                    return false;
                });
                Validator::replacer('license_error', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
                    return str_replace(':error', $parameters[0], $message);
                });
            }
        
            private function changeDefaultSettings()
            {
                ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
                ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', 1000000000);
        
                // Laravel 5.5 to 5.6 compatibility
                Blade::withoutDoubleEncoding();
        
                // Check if HTTPS (including proxy case)
                $isSecure = false;
                if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strcasecmp($_SERVER['HTTPS'], 'on') == 0) {
                    $isSecure = true;
                } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && strcasecmp($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') == 0 || !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL']) && strcasecmp($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'], 'on') == 0) {
                    $isSecure = true;
                }
        
                if ($isSecure) {
                    URL::forceScheme('https');
                }
        
                // HTTP or HTTPS
                // parse_url will return either 'http' or 'https'
                //$scheme = parse_url(config('app.url'), PHP_URL_SCHEME);
                //if (!empty($scheme)) {
                //    URL::forceScheme($scheme);
                //}
        
                // Fix Laravel 5.4 error
                // [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
                // SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
                Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        
                if (!\App::runningInConsole()) {
                    // This is just a trick for getting Controller name in view
                    // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549660/get-laravel-5-controller-name-in-view
                    // @todo: fix this anti-pattern
                    app('view')->composer('*', function ($view) {
                        $route = app('request')->route();
                        if (is_null($route)) {
                            return;
                        }
        
                        $action = app('request')->route()->getAction();
        
                        if (!array_key_exists('controller', $action)) {
                            return;
                        }
        
                        $controller = class_basename($action['controller']);
                        list($controller, $action) = explode('@', $controller);
                        $view->with(compact('controller', 'action'));
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding the stacktrace and your AppServiceProvider?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited the code as you asked.
Please have a look @ClémentBaconnier

Comment: From the stacktrace, you can see that Livewire uses `'controller' => 'Livewire\\Controllers\\HttpConnectionHandler'` but from your AppServiceProvider you're exploding `list($controller, $action) = explode('@', 'Livewire\\Controllers\\HttpConnectionHandler');` to an array, but since `controller` does not contains `@` you get an error.